# Разделение значние ячейки в строке через sql запрос

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, pivot

Таков вопрос. Я подозреваю, что это относится к функциям pivot/unpivot, но все же не уверен. Имеем входную таблицу со следующей структурой: 
id - int 
name - string 
date - decimal. 
К сожалению изменить структуру таблицы нет возможности.

На таблицу приходит строка

*1 Артем 2018020320180204.*

Я выгружаю строку в другую таблицу. Но поскольку дат две нужно чтобы в другой таблице появилось две строки с каждой датой в отельности

*1 Артем 20180203 

1 Артем 20180204*

Как офрмить sql запрос? Или хотябы в каком направлении двигаться?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: *в каком направлении двигаться?* Двигайся к выяснению точных имени и версии SQL-сервера.

Comment: Без вашего усатого сарказма никак. HIVE 2.2.0

Comment: Ну как бы имеется встроенная строковая функция по фамилии substr() ( https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=69408918 ). Последняя дата тянется выражением `SUBSTR(@string,-8)`, а предпоследняя выражением `SUBSTR(@string,-16,8)`.

Comment: Ну а первые два поля вынимаются с помощью функции substring_index() выражениями `SUBSTRING_INDEX(@string,' ',1)` и `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@string,' ',2),' ',-1)` соответственно (если второе поле, там, где в примере данных *'Артем'*, не содержит пробелов).